# Keras model not working (loss not decreasing and accuracy stays at zero)

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, neural-network

I'm new to Keras/Tensorflow and built this model using this proprietary data to estimate, given distance from a user and a store, how much time it takes for the store to deliver to the user.

It's as simple as this:

**Distance (m)**  |   **Time (min)**

5823       |        20.59

5822      |         21.00

6728      |        26.41

6114      |        17.64

6728     | 24.18

1970    | 11.00

I have 5000 pairs of these relations and plotting them gives me the following visualization:

[image]

I'm trying to build a model to predict what's the maximum distance such that the delivery time is always below 10min.

```
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.optimizers import SGD


model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(4, activation = 'relu'))
model.add(Dense(4, activation = 'relu'))
model.add(Dense(4, activation = 'relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation = 'sigmoid'))

opt = SGD(lr=0.01)
model.compile(optimizer = opt, loss = 'mean_squared_error', metrics=["accuracy"])
model.fit(X_train, Y_train, epochs = 500)
```

When it trains, it gives me the following:

[image: following]

**What is happening? How can I fix it?**

Answer (score 0):

Your data has a large amount of variance. As such, neural networks right off the bat may not be the best way to model your data. From a data science perspective there are some things you need to address before using a ML model:

1. You need to transform the data so that the overall variance is low. You can try adding another dimension to the data based on some transform and then apply a NN.
2. You need to normalize data so the dependent and independent variables share the same range of values (eg. 0 to 1).

Comment: Normalizing the data would mean I divide distance the maximum value of distance and do the same for time? This way both distance and time would have 0 to 1 values, right?

Comment: what would you recomend for 1. Log the values to decrease variance, for instance? Or is there another transform function you think would be better?